# Python pyodbc for Teradata error 10054 connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sql, connection, teradata, pyodbc

I am trying to pull a query using pyodbc and it keeps returning a reset by peer error, I can run the query no issue 100% of the time in Teradata SQL Assistant.
This happens with one other query I use but everything else I have done works using the same code.

I have tried running it multiple times, always works in Teradata SQL Assistant but not in python. Hundreds of other queries have worked with no issue, only two have given issues. I have tried slightly changing the queries with no luck. 
I also tried in R with RODBC and it worked there.

I asked our DBA team and they said they have no process that would automatically boot that process and there is no issues with the query.

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas.io.sql as psql

connection_info = 'DSN=xxxxxx'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info)

sql1 = '''
    QUERY HERE
    '''

df = psql.read_sql_query(sql1, conn)
```

expect df to = resuls, instead get the following error:
10054 WSA E ConnReset: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Without some other error message this usually indicates the TCP session was broken by something in the middle, e.g. network load balancer thought it was idle too long. Are these queries particularly long-running?

Comment: One runs in 30 seconds the other in about 5 min. We have some 15 minute queries that run successfully every day.

Comment: Doesn't seem long enough for anything to "time out". This can be a very difficult type of issue to troubleshoot. Maybe instead of generic pyodbc you could try Teradata python package (teradatasql), though I'm not certain that will make a difference.

Comment: that is my next step to try. Just weird that a simple query would not run while all others do.

Comment: It is a little hard to figure out the teradatasql module. And it is weird that the pyodbc works sometimes and not others.


for teradatasql i came up with this code that seems slow but worked, except it is not pulling in headers. the commented line is how i tried to play and get it but of course did not work.

`python
import pandas as pd

import teradatasql
con = teradatasql.connect(host="host", user="user", password="pw")

sql = '''
        SELECT
        '''
        
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
#df.columns = cur.column_name()
`

Comment: Just let pandas figure it out. `df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con)`